# Unable to use post method api in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on Nodejs and i am using expressjs, Right now i am trying to run "adduser" api(post method api) but i am getting following message in console.log

```
[object object]
```

Here is my routes file code

```
const express = require('express');
const apiController = require('../controllers/api.controller');
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/new', apiController.addUser);
A
```

nd here is my controller file (api.controller.js)

```
const addUser = async (req, res) => {
   const { firstName, lastName, age } = req.body;

    console.log('post data is '+ req.body);
    console.log('first name is '+ lastName);
    console.log('age is '+ age);

    if (!firstName || !firstName.trim() || !lastName || !lastName.trim() || age == null || age < 0)
        return res.status(400).send({ statusCode: 400, statusMessage: 'Bad Request', message: null, data: null });

    try {
        const user = new User(firstName, lastName, age);
        await user.save();

        res.status(201).send({
            statusCode: 201,
            statusMessage: 'Created',
            message: 'Successfully created a user.',
            data: null,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
            statusCode: 500,
            statusMessage: 'Internal Server Error',
            message: null,
            data: null,
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: I can't see any way that code would generate that log message. Is that log message from your server side code or is it from client-side code you haven't shown us?

Comment: All else being equal, I would expect `const { firstName, lastName, age } = req.body;` to throw an except as you have no body parsing middleware.

Comment: Bah. Made a typo. "Exception".

Comment: Where is `ExpressApplication` defined (i.e., `const app = express()`? Is `router` mounted to `app` (i.e., `app.use("/users", router)`? What are you sending as request (body, headers) and how?

Comment: Also, as @Quentin pointed out, `body-parser` middleware is missing and it will not parse your request to JSON and `req.body` will be `undefined`

Comment: @AbrarHossain can you post your answer so i can check at my side

Answer (score 0):

```
const addUser = async (req, res) => {
const { firstName, lastName, age } = req.body;

 console.log('post data is '+ req.body);
 console.log('first name is '+ lastName);
 console.log('age is '+ age);

 if (!firstName || !firstName.trim() || !lastName || !lastName.trim() || 
age == null || age < 0)
     return res.status(400).send({ statusCode: 400, statusMessage: 'Bad 
Request', message: null, data: null });

try {
    const user = new schema({firstName, lastName, age});
    await user.save();

   res.status(201).send({
       statusCode: 201,
       statusMessage: 'Created',
       message: 'Successfully created a user.',
       data: null,
   });
  } catch (err) {
   res.status(500).send({
       statusCode: 500,
       statusMessage: 'Internal Server Error',
       message: null,
       data: null,
   });
 }
};
```

use it  `const user = new schema({firstName, lastName, age});` **req.body** Values check in schema please add in **object { }**

make sure app.js file you require `app.use(express.json());`